# Unable to find the image edge option in Xcode 8 for UIButton

Tags: uibutton, uistoryboard, xcode8

As I am easily get the image edge option in `Xcode 7` using `storyboard -> Attribute inspector` but I did not get the option in `Xcode 8`.

Comment: You will find the image edge option in Size inspector of Storyboard for Xcode 8. Please review my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below screenshot for viewing the image edge option in Xcode 8.

[image: Scrrenshot]